# Flutter callback / passing function as a parameter problem

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to pass a function as a parameter. My code runs but the function doesn't fire.

I have a Holiday class

```
  final VoidCallback callback;
  Holiday(this.holidayStart, this.holidayEnd, this.holidayDuration, this.callback);
```

Inside the Holiday class I have a function to build a widget with a button. here I use...

```
   onPressed: () {
       callback;
   },
```

In my main.dart file when I create a new instance of Holiday I pass a function like this....

```
holidays.add(Holiday(startSelected, endSelected, stay, () { print('pressed'); }))
```

Everything compiles fine but pressed is never printed. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you passed function that does nothing because you put callback but don't call it (via () at the end or .call()).
You should write `onPressed: callback,`
or `onPressed: () {  callback(); },`

Comment: Ah thank you! knew it would be something silly. I changed it to your first suggestion.